Помогите, требуется помощь в изменении пароля у графический интерфейс PgAdmin4?
После установки PostgreSQL и PgAdmin4 на новом компьютере под управлением Windows 10, при попытке запустить PgAdmin4 возникает запрос на ввод пароля для пользователя 'postgres'. Однако после ввода пароля появляется ошибка, несмотря на несколько переустановок и проверку настроек, включая состояние PostgreSQL в сервисах и настройки брандмауэра. При первом запуска PgAdmin4 пароль не спрашивали. При перезагрузки программы добавления пароля все ровно не спрашивают.


Установлена версия pgAdmin 4 v8.9 (released June 27, 2024)
